# Porque não consigo fazer o grid system na minha página php?

Tags: php, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Estou a começar um projeto para a universidade e não consigo fazer o grid system na tag do main content. Estou a tentar a bastante tempo!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não consigo implementar o grid!
Este é o meu código..

`

```
<img src="../Logincheck/assets/img/image2.png" class="company-logo"><br>
        <div id="welcome">
            <b><?php echo $result['username'] ?> </b>
        </div>

    <div class="sidebar-links">
                <div class="link-blue"> 
                    <a href="logout.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout
                    </a>
                </div>

                    <div class="link-orange selected">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home
            </a>
                    </div>

        <div class="link-blue ">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i>Tables
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">Automóveis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Motociclos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Caravanas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Autocarros</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="link-red">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> Inserir
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">Automóveis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Motociclos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Caravanas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Autocarros</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="link-yellow">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>Estado
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">Automóveis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Motociclos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Caravanas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Autocarros</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>



                    <div class="link-blue">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>Reservas
            </a>

        </div>

                <div class="link-red">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i>Clientes
            </a>

        </div>
                <div class="link-green">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-money"></i>Budget Maker
            </a>
                    </div>

                <div class="link-blue">

            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>Estatísticas
            </a>
                    </div>

    </div>

</aside>

<div class="main-content">

    <div class="menu">

                <!--div de número de viaturas que a empresa possui-->
                <div id="ncf" style="color:black; background-color: yellow">
                    <div style="font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif; align-content: center">
                    <?php 
                    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM vehicle";
                    $numcars = $connect->query($sql1);

                     if ($result = $numcars ) {

                      $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
                      print  'Viaturas da empresa'.'<br>'.$row_cnt;





                    }else{
                        echo 'sem viaturas';
                    }


                    ?></div>
                </div>

                <!--div número de clientes-->
                <div id="nclts"></div>

                <!--div número de reservas (ultima semana)-->
                <div id="nrsv"></div>

                <!--div de país com mais viaturas da empresa-->
                <div id="pvemp"></div>

                <!--div dados de funcionário-->
                <div ids="dfunc"></div>

                <!--div download aplicação mobile-->
                <div id="dapk"></div>

                <!--div viatura mais requisitada do mês-->
                <div id="vmrm"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

`

Eu já tentei fazer o grid, no entanto mantém sempre a formatação da imagem acima e não consigo perceber porque! Alguém me consegue ajudar por favor?

update

Aqui está o css.

```css
.main-content {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 max-width: 1000px;
 padding-top: 40px;
 margin: 0 0 40px 260px;

}

#welcome{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.sidebar-left-collapse {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #292c2f;
 width: 180px;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 20px 0;
}

.sidebar-left-collapse > img {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: Cookie, cursive;
 width: 122px;
 height: 122px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 44px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 2.6;
 border-radius: 50%;
        background-image: url(../Logincheck/assets/img/image1.png);
}

.sidebar-left-collapse .sidebar-links {
 margin: 30px auto;
}

.sidebar-links div > a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 5px;
 background-color: #35393e;
 text-align: left;
 color:  #b3bcc5;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 2;
 border-left-width: 2px;
 border-left-style: solid;
}

.sidebar-links div.selected > a{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 color: #565d63;
 line-height: 2.3;
 margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-links div > a i.fa {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 top: 3px;
 width: 40px;
 text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-links div ul.sub-links {
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 30px;
 color:  #b3bcc5;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 24px;
 margin: 0;
 transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidebar-links div.selected ul.sub-links {
 max-height: 150px;
 padding: 12px 0 12px 30px;
}

.sidebar-links div .sub-links a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #b3bcc5;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

/* Link Colors */
.sidebar-links div.link-orange > a {
 border-color: #FFA500;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-orange > a i.fa {
 color: #FFA500;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-blue > a {
 border-color: #487db2;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-blue > a i.fa {
 color: #487db2;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-red > a {
 border-color: #da4545;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-red > a i.fa {
 color: #da4545;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-yellow > a {
 border-color: #d0d237;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-yellow > a i.fa {
 color: #d0d237;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-green > a {
 border-color: #86be2e;
}

.sidebar-links div.link-green > a i.fa {
 color: #86be2e;
}

/* Making the sidebar responsive */

@media (max-width: 900px) {

 .main-content{
  max-width: none;
  padding: 70px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
 }

 .sidebar-left-collapse {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: static;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
 }

 .sidebar-left-collapse .sidebar-links {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
 }

 .sidebar-links div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
 }

 .sidebar-links div > a {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-left: none;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-style: solid;
 }

 .sidebar-links div > a i.fa {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
 }

 .sidebar-links div ul.sub-links {
  display: none;
 }

 .sidebar-links div.selected .sub-links {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

 .sidebar-links div.selected .sub-links li {
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .sidebar-links div.selected .sub-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #748290;
 }

}

/* Smartphone version */

@media (max-width: 450px) {

 .main-content{
  padding: 90px 20px;
 }

 .sidebar-left-collapse {
  padding: 20px 0;
 }

 .sidebar-left-collapse .sidebar-links {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  position: relative;
 }

 .sidebar-links div {
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
 }

 .sidebar-links div > a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: none;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-style: solid;
 }

 .sidebar-links div > a i.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
 }

 .sidebar-links div.selected .sub-links {
  bottom: -90px;
 }

}

/* Removing margins and paddings from the body, so that
    the sidebar takes the full height of the page */

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu neste trecho de código não coloquei o grid... porque quando meto o grid o resultado da exatamente igual ao da imagem , mas vou fazer update e por o css

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Alexandre!

Bom, uma coisa que sempre me ajuda no desenvolvimento web é setar no styles uma borda para todas as divs, assim a visualização da estrutura fica melhor para encontrarmos o espaço onde cada elemento fica.

No caso da sua estrutura ela precisa funcionar assim:

- Uma div que contém todo o conteúdo do site.
- A div com o menu
- E a div com o conteúdo que não pertence ao menu

A partir disso já da pra imaginar bem a estrutura desse layout, eu montei um código seguindo algumas definições suas de css :

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  width: 30%; /* Ajuste a largura para as demais telas */
  display:inline;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li{
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #35393e;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 180px;
  color: #b3bcc5;
  font-family: Cookie, cursive;
}

.conteudo {
  width: 80%;
  display:inline;
}

.m-home {
  border-left: 2px solid #FFA500;
}
.m-tables {
  border-left: 2px solid #487db2; 
}
.m-inserir {
   border-left: 2px solid  #da4545;
}
.m-estados {
  border-left: 2px solid #d0d237;
}
.m-reservas {
  border-left: 2px solid #487db2;
}
.m-clientes {
  border-left: 2px solid #da4545;
}
.m-bmaker {
  border-left: 2px solid #86be2e;
}
.m-estatisticas {
  border-left: 2px solid #487db2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    menu
    
    <ul>
      <li class="m-home"> <img src="logo.png"> Home </li>
      <li class="m-tables"> <img src="logo.png"> Tables </li>
      <li class="m-inserir">   <img src="logo.png"> Inserir </li>
      <li class="m-estados">  <img src="logo.png"> Estado </li>
      <li class="m-reservas">  <img src="logo.png"> Reservas </li>
      <li class="m-clientes">  <img src="logo.png"> Clientes </li>
      <li class="m-bmaker"> <img src="logo.png"> Budget Maker </li>
      <li class="m-estatisticas"> <img src="logo.png"> Estatísticas </li>
     </ul>
    
  </div>
  <div class="conteudo">
    conteudo 
    
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum nisi urna euismod ullamcorper ipsum, lobortis cras gravida ultricies tempus ultricies sodales, conubia orci lacus ac porttitor. laoreet lorem habitasse volutpat est cras quisque adipiscing fermentum scelerisque praesent id, senectus bibendum diam aenean enim ante praesent platea adipiscing. metus enim adipiscing amet tristique massa gravida nisl ac sed quis, lobortis orci aptent metus eleifend turpis nam duis ultricies. aliquam sed bibendum mollis conubia etiam netus sagittis pulvinar quam, suspendisse ac purus tempor porttitor dapibus consectetur suspendisse. ut pharetra dui amet fermentum eros tempor, condimentum sem metus cras bibendum magna tristique, blandit etiam aenean aptent posuere. 
    </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Quando você for criar menus, de preferência para criá-los com listas, e depois com o CSS você manipula como desejar.

Deixei no código o texto menu e conteúdo, para você remover após os teste.

Quando editar o arquivo CSS, sempre comece setando o **body** e depois as demais propriedades e classes!

Espero ter te ajudado.